# Is it possible to say "Will won't"

Tags: modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs, modality

*Will* is usually used to indicate future event, as in

> *I **will** go to school*

However, it can also function as a modal auxiliary expressing a *willingness* or *refusal*. Like

> *I **won't** go to school*

But I wonder, is it possible to say *"will won't"* to indicate a refusal in future. For example,

> *I **will won't** go to school*

I know, I can just say *"I will refuse to.."* but I don't think it sounds idiomatic(to my non-native ears). But, I want to know, is this construction possible and idiomatic?

Comment: "I will refuse to" sounds perfectly normal to this native US English speaker.  As RichF points out, *won't* already means *will not*, so it's already in the future, and you don't have to specify that again, unless you need to be very specific about it for some reason (like "Today I will go to school, but tomorrow I won't.")

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not grammatical.  Consider the meaning of **won't**.  It is nothing more than a contraction of **will not**.  Thus in formal English, your last example would read:

> I will will not go to school.

Even if it were legal, I penalize it 99 points for ugliness.  You'll just have to stick to boring alternatives like you stated, "I will refuse to go to school." Another alternative case:

> Next year I will avoid school altogether.